# PHP Curl - Cookies problem

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I am trying to grab my amazon associates stats automatically via cUrl. However I am falling down at the first hurdle; logging in.

When I use the following code:

```
    $url = 'https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html';
    $post_data = "action=sign-in&email=$username&password=$password";

    $fp = fopen('/my/path/to/cookie.txt', 'w');
    fclose($fp);

    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/my/path/to/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my/path/to/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    echo curl_exec($login);
    curl_close($login);
```

I get the following output:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2011 22:08:39 GMT Server: Server
>   x-amz-id-1: 1NNZMSS8X73EE0G7HKW8 x-amz-id-2:
>   HRW1ZoN4KVzDCp/tS5E7l+7fn9XGH2k/T7qxzi+WLOw= Set-cookie:
>   session-id-time=1317279600l; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Thu
>   Sep 29 07:00:00 2011 GMT Set-cookie: session-id=181-7755537-2127814;
>   path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Thu Sep 29 07:00:00 2011 GMT Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Cneonction: close Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Please Enable Cookies
>   to Continue
>
> To continue shopping at Amazon.com, please enable cookies in your Web
>   browser.  Learn more about cookies and how to enable them.
>
> Once you have enabled cookies in your browser, please click on the
>   button below to return to the previous page.

cookie.txt contains the following:

> # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
>
> # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
>
> # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
>
> .amazon.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1317279600  session-id-time 1317279600l
>
> .amazon.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1317279600  session-id  181-7755537-2127814

Live HTTP headers:

> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html
>
> POST /gp/flex/sign-in/select.html HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> affiliate-program.amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0;
>
> rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
>
> Referer: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/ Cookie:
>
> apn-user-id=P0000000000; session-id-time=1317366000l;
>
> session-id=182-9139891-5240049;
>
> __utma=125759317.157031897.1316727783.1316727783.1316795373.2;
>
> __utmz=125759317.1316727783.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; __utmv=125759317.koicarandsup-20;
>
> x-main=qIM@jFtaFnr4KaiFFutR7WZ1QkQHqoq9;
>
> at-main=4|eaxYjMp+5TWMiQOn6gROkHUvCfKF3Y9hkvacYbU0+fzL3Pr1ejcGt78Tb6W5zvUYj67hWyx3AuNd3UparIBCnnrL62d5IMyn7zeFKr7GfjnPvjjaGOPArk7n7tr7go+QgBU6OZ0hKse6MJIdApDrSe2cI0Mz9XDvbumEU5twDKgq338hejMR23IXuWrvq1o0hcfN6DS0oabY7mVIddSMig==;
>
> __utmb=125759317; __utmc=125759317 Content-Type:
>
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 1276
>
> sessionId=182-9139891-
>   5240049&path=%2Fgp%2Fassociates%2Flogin%2Flogin.html&query=returl%3D%2Fgp%2Fassociates%2Fjoin%2Flanding%2Fmain.html%26retquery%3D&action=sign-in&mode=1&email=xxx&password=xxx&x=31&y=18&metadata1=xppc1AIU%2Fl8IERp8RJxYooTCV9Vo2Nico9wyEvW9ByghGgc%2FSNU8XqMQnjgshs3DZpFQgLXCAT1qAama%2Bj5WBGxvTRiC45v6Am7hMY99RwJfUIozi5v1ZkwV%2Bcjp9PecvpcPSxLVuwOF4QSf7Q%2BPxNwlxLm5nHXqSNPwmw5Ezg2ENIagMWcrwuDlp50%2B0XKi0e8yyawdc5TjH%2BhGXz12KABRLoH1WuTSwAWleHzGzBUN515WgRMElB583b9h%2FoDINumjmwwsHsjzXjLaEjYaM1w6nw%2F5fqmpABPcN31D7wgDQoOi1xxIyUtZceAa3rwwUxKvpZecStM2T6QtSJhx6YdpLNmHwGSdhkBrsCQVlcLruKNMnUVrb%2FZni3le380YsUeIsVZy113lqayCwla9vwvDTA4mstx2YTKtTU1NOzfblMlYBEL4rhLN1fpeF0EaiAoiatLb1kH%2BCvt6tp78KyPCd0XeEBGqMeDWm2b%2FBSg%2BUqVLBMSeHtJ4VZXxMaWhodZZYU0uxUNwL8hCVruO5KxSbssorByNybuPx%2FmkS87UZMDB62VALgb90MUXLvbVX%2BcmizzBkmwCs3Q6ampHa40NIYQKXTCCnGjVUwavCPv73OrMA8OjVJX3h371m3OHvzpBKRTFG5uiTfZoaaPI%2FYxikE2v99%2FaR3vlwkTZfOhM%2Fba9seIbMpxArTj6ekpmTLbU5LwKn2yVbiAZgsUuFSCNcQMlE%2FJ9nAIuYZ2guks0Zz%2BPhJ07TOXuTscuc%2Fm0wgqqluPq5NShRINoiGLjiKva6ngslLoQWeKovNwYyVCyNfuwsZ7BIo6%2Fo7yaEfIK6Yb%2BZPMommN%2FI7BFrlW7wrWmaG%2FgbtSx1bg9A5DgtKBDI21j3ibebBZVN%2FP2ZrEB6upCDHEKa1pMCkP6nbOhu%2BxcrNYS%2FyS6e0bv3WiWqugclX%2FnYmBWBdNunCFtI8LKU%2FMvhDT820M%3D
>
> HTTP/1.1 302 MovedTemporarily Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:35 GMT
>
> Server: Server x-amz-id-1: 1JGFY8JCATS8GCJ05WP3 x-amz-id-2:
>
> vNYWJ+3yN1Qrya1cxENZdlFuZNF4Yc4uYhCmoR3UFBU= Set-Cookie:
>
> at-main=4|3iPYr7E1Pn32BbMI4MHFaMtbn/0v54qEG1Jn9Pk+7Hi2Cws1f+jBSUt9oyBzrpy6BX1XCsZ/qoJlbswA0G2U3L9Yhec4CjSlsLZM+mEPRs/AiNAbvuUDzj9wL1HI2x+e7tBqDLhK+fas6R562qkQBX+9Y7bhE1St11hjislFijGuTcbtr+5mUz1FuweEFaH/xtHacsJ3Yth9iOiska0CbQ==;
>
> path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue Jan 01 08:00:01 2036 GMT;
>
> secure Set-Cookie: ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; path=/;
>
> domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue Jan 01 08:00:01 2036 GMT Location:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/join/landing/main.html
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Encoding: gzip nnCoection:
>
> close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html;
>
> charset=UTF-8
>
> ---
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/join/landing/main.html
>
> GET /gp/associates/join/landing/main.html HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> affiliate-program.amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0;
>
> rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
>
> Referer: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/ Cookie:
>
> apn-user-id=P0000000000; session-id-time=1317366000l;
>
> session-id=182-9139891-5240049;
>
> __utma=125759317.157031897.1316727783.1316727783.1316795373.2;
>
> __utmz=125759317.1316727783.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; __utmv=125759317.koicarandsup-20;
>
> x-main=qIM@jFtaFnr4KaiFFutR7WZ1QkQHqoq9;
>
> at-main=4|3iPYr7E1Pn32BbMI4MHFaMtbn/0v54qEG1Jn9Pk+7Hi2Cws1f+jBSUt9oyBzrpy6BX1XCsZ/qoJlbswA0G2U3L9Yhec4CjSlsLZM+mEPRs/AiNAbvuUDzj9wL1HI2x+e7tBqDLhK+fas6R562qkQBX+9Y7bhE1St11hjislFijGuTcbtr+5mUz1FuweEFaH/xtHacsJ3Yth9iOiska0CbQ==;
>
> __utmb=125759317; __utmc=125759317
>
> HTTP/1.1 302 MovedTemporarily Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:36 GMT
>
> Server: Server x-amz-id-1: 0DVGSNJ16FJ7BZSXKZEA x-amz-id-2:
>
> 3zBVVCqaFC6uLEb69n0ImqYEWcveHC/fr3DWJZ9XwfU= Set-Cookie:
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue
>
> Jan 01 08:00:01 2036 GMT Location:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Content-Encoding: gzip Cneonction:
>
> close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html;
>
> charset=UTF-8
>
> ---
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> GET /gp/associates/network/main.html HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> affiliate-program.amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0;
>
> rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive
>
> Referer: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/ Cookie:
>
> apn-user-id=P0000000000; session-id-time=1317366000l;
>
> session-id=182-9139891-5240049;
>
> __utma=125759317.157031897.1316727783.1316727783.1316795373.2;
>
> __utmz=125759317.1316727783.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; __utmv=125759317.koicarandsup-20;
>
> x-main=qIM@jFtaFnr4KaiFFutR7WZ1QkQHqoq9;
>
> at-main=4|3iPYr7E1Pn32BbMI4MHFaMtbn/0v54qEG1Jn9Pk+7Hi2Cws1f+jBSUt9oyBzrpy6BX1XCsZ/qoJlbswA0G2U3L9Yhec4CjSlsLZM+mEPRs/AiNAbvuUDzj9wL1HI2x+e7tBqDLhK+fas6R562qkQBX+9Y7bhE1St11hjislFijGuTcbtr+5mUz1FuweEFaH/xtHacsJ3Yth9iOiska0CbQ==;
>
> __utmb=125759317; __utmc=125759317
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:36 GMT Server: Server
>
> x-amz-id-1: 02WEQDKB29RGKP5T4NWE x-amz-id-2:
>
> xFfF8ncVlxX9KZtDLganiEY4CcDu+qXwkV5CBJGrKWY= Set-Cookie:
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; path=/; domain=.amazon.com; expires=Tue
>
> Jan 01 08:00:01 2036 GMT Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>
> Content-Encoding: gzip Cneonction: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> ---
>
> V192206992.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/associates/network/thumb-slideshow-widget.*V192206992*.jpg
>
> GET
>
> /images/G/01/associates/network/thumb-slideshow-widget.*V192206992*.jpg
>
> HTTP/1.1 Host: images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>
> (Windows NT 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 4119 Last-Modified:
>
> Wed, 02 Jun 2010 17:03:17 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> HIT from cdn-images.amazon.com:8080, MISS from
>
> cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: max-age=607570264 Date:
>
> Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41WtSRWclnL.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/41WtSRWclnL.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1317 Last-Modified:
>
> Thu, 26 May 2011 11:17:40 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> HIT from cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: public,
>
> max-age=628443948 Expires: Sat, 23 Aug 2031 08:16:25 GMT Date: Fri, 23
>
> Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417XQ0XwQuL.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/417XQ0XwQuL.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1321 Last-Modified:
>
> Thu, 29 Jul 2010 04:26:28 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg Cache-Control:
>
> public, max-age=628496714 Expires: Sat, 23 Aug 2031 22:55:51 GMT Date:
>
> Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417tb3B43YL.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/417tb3B43YL.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 2462 Last-Modified:
>
> Fri, 26 Jun 2009 04:52:12 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> HIT from cdn-images.amazon.com:8080, MISS from
>
> cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: max-age=607635331 Date:
>
> Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41sh5uiQ83L.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/41sh5uiQ83L.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1341 Last-Modified:
>
> Thu, 15 Sep 2011 20:05:25 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> MISS from cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: public,
>
> max-age=630611997 Expires: Wed, 17 Sep 2031 10:30:34 GMT Date: Fri, 23
>
> Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmn=61668861&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-gb&utmje=1&utmfl=10.3%20r183&utmdt=Amazon.com%20Associates%20Central%20-%20Home&utmhn=affiliate-program.amazon.com&utmr=0&utmp=/gp/associates/network/main.html">https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/_utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmn=61668861&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-gb&utmje=1&utmfl=10.3%20r183&utmdt=Amazon.com%20Associates%20Central%20-%20Home&utmhn=affiliate-program.amazon.com&utmr=0&utmp=/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> GET
>
> /__utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmn=61668861&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-
>   gb&utmje=1&utmfl=10.3%20r183&utmdt=Amazon.com%20Associates%20Central%20-%20Home&utmhn=affiliate-program.amazon.com&utmr=0&utmp=/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 Host: affiliate-program.amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>
> (Windows NT 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> Cookie: apn-user-id=P0000000000; session-id-time=1317366000l;
>
> session-id=182-9139891-5240049;
>
> __utma=125759317.157031897.1316727783.1316727783.1316795373.2;
>
> __utmz=125759317.1316727783.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; __utmv=125759317.koicarandsup-20;
>
> x-main=qIM@jFtaFnr4KaiFFutR7WZ1QkQHqoq9;
>
> at-main=4|3iPYr7E1Pn32BbMI4MHFaMtbn/0v54qEG1Jn9Pk+7Hi2Cws1f+jBSUt9oyBzrpy6BX1XCsZ/qoJlbswA0G2U3L9Yhec4CjSlsLZM+mEPRs/AiNAbvuUDzj9wL1HI2x+e7tBqDLhK+fas6R562qkQBX+9Y7bhE1St11hjislFijGuTcbtr+5mUz1FuweEFaH/xtHacsJ3Yth9iOiska0CbQ==;
>
> __utmb=125759317; __utmc=125759317
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Server: Server
>
> Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 11:22:34 GMT Etag: "23-35b3d280"
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 35 Cneonction: close
>
> Content-Type: image/gif
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51993R08WLL.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/51993R08WLL.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1325 Last-Modified:
>
> Tue, 27 Jul 2010 16:47:41 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> MISS from cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: public,
>
> max-age=628244375 Expires: Thu, 21 Aug 2031 00:50:12 GMT Date: Fri, 23
>
> Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41is%2B997KUL.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/41is%2B997KUL.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1662 Last-Modified:
>
> Sun, 11 Nov 2007 01:27:41 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> MISS from cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: public,
>
> max-age=628487843 Expires: Sat, 23 Aug 2031 20:28:00 GMT Date: Fri, 23
>
> Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/518ISDAvx1L.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/518ISDAvx1L.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1111 Last-Modified:
>
> Tue, 27 Jul 2010 00:37:08 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> MISS from cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: public,
>
> max-age=628003065 Expires: Mon, 18 Aug 2031 05:48:22 GMT Date: Fri, 23
>
> Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> SL75.jpg">https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4155OOdySdL.*SL75*.jpg
>
> GET /images/I/4155OOdySdL.*SL75*.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>
> 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Server Content-Length: 1494 Last-Modified:
>
> Thu, 20 Aug 2009 15:52:47 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg X-Cache-Lookup:
>
> MISS from cdn-images.amazon.com:10080 Cache-Control: public,
>
> max-age=630336792 Expires: Sun, 14 Sep 2031 06:03:49 GMT Date: Fri, 23
>
> Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---
>
> utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmt=var&utmn=1408273993">https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/_utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmt=var&utmn=1408273993
>
> GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=1&utmt=var&utmn=1408273993 HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> affiliate-program.amazon.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0;
>
> rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 Accept:
>
> image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Charset:
>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>
> https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/main.html
>
> Cookie: apn-user-id=P0000000000; session-id-time=1317366000l;
>
> session-id=182-9139891-5240049;
>
> __utma=125759317.157031897.1316727783.1316727783.1316795373.2;
>
> __utmz=125759317.1316727783.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
>
> ubid-main=190-8295480-4625243; __utmv=125759317.koicarandsup-20;
>
> x-main=qIM@jFtaFnr4KaiFFutR7WZ1QkQHqoq9;
>
> at-main=4|3iPYr7E1Pn32BbMI4MHFaMtbn/0v54qEG1Jn9Pk+7Hi2Cws1f+jBSUt9oyBzrpy6BX1XCsZ/qoJlbswA0G2U3L9Yhec4CjSlsLZM+mEPRs/AiNAbvuUDzj9wL1HI2x+e7tBqDLhK+fas6R562qkQBX+9Y7bhE1St11hjislFijGuTcbtr+5mUz1FuweEFaH/xtHacsJ3Yth9iOiska0CbQ==;
>
> __utmb=125759317; __utmc=125759317
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2011 16:30:37 GMT Server: Server
>
> Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 11:22:34 GMT Etag: "23-35b3d280"
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 35 Cneonction: close
>
> Content-Type: image/gif
>
> ---

Can anyone shed some light on why this is not working?

Comment: That message makes me think they may have some javascript code that attempts to set or read a cookie from another request.  Try using livehttpheaders or perhaps wireshark to sniff a normal login request to their site and see if you notice any other URLs being hit, in particular some sort of cookie check.  Or turn followlocation off and see if there is any javascript for testing cookies on a page that you may be redirected past.

Comment: Looks like several cookies are not being set, including at-main which I think is important.  Try getting rid of the curlopt_cookiesession option, I don't know how it behaves with followlocation, but I don't think its necessary to have.  All that does is delete certain session cookies before starting.

Comment: Also, are you sure you have the right log in URL?  If I go to the url you are using in my browser, I get redirected somewhere else, and the action for the sign in form is `https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin`  Also there is a security token you will need to extract from the HTML before logging in, it is appActionToken.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT:** This code is broken as of June 2016.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818684/login-to-amazon-using-curl/33839853#33839853) for explanation and potential workaround.  The same technology mentioned in the previous link was added to associates' login.

---

I wrote this code up and it works well for me, in the last var_dump I see all my account info and things like that.  If you don't delete the cookies, you can make subsequent curl requests to protected pages with your login.

Hopefully this can help you learn about how to do it.  A lot of times on big sites you need to visit the login page to get cookies set, and also they usually have csrf tokens on the forms you need to submit with them.

Of course if amazon changes their forms or url's around a bit, this will have to be adapted some, but hopefully they don't do that too often.

```
<?php

$email    = 'you@yoursite.com';
$password = 'password';

// initial login page which redirects to correct sign in page, sets some cookies
$URL = 'https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/join/landing/main.html';

$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'amazoncookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'amazoncookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,  fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$page = curl_exec($ch);

//var_dump($page);exit;

// try to find the actual login form
if (!preg_match('/<form name="sign_in".*?<\/form>/is', $page, $form)) {
    die('Failed to find log in form!');
}

$form = $form[0];

// find the action of the login form
if (!preg_match('/action=(?:\'|")?([^\s\'">]+)/i', $form, $action)) {
    die('Failed to find login form url');
}

$URL2 = $action[1]; // this is our new post url

// find all hidden fields which we need to send with our login, this includes security tokens
$count = preg_match_all('/<input type="hidden"\s*name="([^"]*)"\s*value="([^"]*)"/i', $form, $hiddenFields);

$postFields = array();

// turn the hidden fields into an array
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $postFields[$hiddenFields[1][$i]] = $hiddenFields[2][$i];
}

// add our login values
$postFields['username'] = $email;
$postFields['password'] = $password;

$post = '';

// convert to string, this won't work as an array, form will not accept multipart/form-data, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
foreach($postFields as $key => $value) {
    $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post = substr($post, 0, -1);

// set additional curl options using our previous options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$page = curl_exec($ch); // make request

var_dump($page); // should be logged in
```

Comment: @drew010: That was brilliant solution. I need to login with different URL.

I don't find URL with openID like you've used in your solution, so I've tried with the $URL="https://sellercentral-japan.amazon.com/gp/sign-in/sign-in.html/ref=pt_login_lgin_login";

In response, it shows login page with this errror message:
"There was an error trying to perform this operation. Please try again in 15 minutes."
It shows same message after 15 min too.

I've posted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061543/how-can-i-login-in-amazon-with-php-curl

Comment: This used to work, but Amazon have since changed their login process, adding some sort of CSFR protection which makes it difficult to log in using cURL. Anyone else had this problem recently (in the last 10 days)?

Comment: @umami Yes even i have the same problem.. You found a fix for that?

Comment: Can you make a script like this for [this](https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&pageId=quarterdeck&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&clientContext=184-5348484-8758301&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&marketPlaceId=A39WRC2IB8YGEK&openid.assoc_handle=quarterdeck&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myhabit.com%2Fsignin&&siteState=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myhabit.com%2Fhomepage%3Fhash%3D) site

Comment: just grab the cookie from homepage. then go to login page with the cookie. it should resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi @user2619381 - I updated the code sample so it now works with their new login pages.

Comment: @drew010 works perfect. I changed it to work with Amazon DE and just had to change the URL and username to email in the property :)

Comment: @drew010 trying to use the with the KDP.amazon.com and get nothing.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to get amazon to set the cookie first.

Try:

```
// 1. Create a cookie file and set basic params
$ckfile = tempnam ("/your/path/to/cookie/folder", "cookie.txt");
$target_host = "https://affiliate-program.amazon.com";
$target_request = "/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html";
$post_data = "action=sign-in&email=$username&password=$password";

// 2. Visit homepage to set cookie
$ch = curl_init ($target_host);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

// 3. Continue
$login = curl_init ($target_host.$target_request);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
echo curl_exec($login);
curl_close($login);
```

Comment: I get the same output as stated in the question (well near enough)