# PHP CURL site login

Tags: php, curl

I want to login to a site automatically using curl. But the site is saying cookies must be enabled in your browser. I searched a lot but couldn't find it. If anyone could help,


After searching a lot in website help, I found out that the site uses two cookies Moodlesession and sessionid. I don't know how to handle them in curl. Please help.


The form is as follows:

```
<form action="http://site_name/login/index.php" method="post" id="login">
      <div class="loginform">
        <div class="form-label"><label for="username">Username</label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="15" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
        <div class="form-label"><label for="password">Password</label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="15" value="">
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
          <input type="hidden" name="testcookies" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The curl script I'm using is:

```
<?php
    $username="myusername";
    $password="mypassword";
    $url="login_url";
    $cookie="cookie.txt";
    $postdata="username=".$username."&password=".$password;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Comment: you have just to enable the cookies of your browser

Comment: Where is cookie.txt and what permission has?

Comment: Currently I'm testing it on local server. The cookie file is in the same folder of the script. I did not set any permissions for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this option to `cURL` configuration:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
```

And ensure you have a file called `cookie.txt` (for example write it to /tmp directory) and give permissions 777 (or make apache user the user of this file and give permissions 644)

I check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522149/php-curl-cookies-problem)

Comment: can you please tell me how to set permissions in windows platform?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, but, afaik, is: Right click in the file, properties, and then in Security you can set the owner and the permissions. You can search in google about how to change permissions searching for "change file permission windows"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to send in the postdata variable the input 'testcookies'. Something like:

```
$postdata="username=".$username."&password=".$password."&testcookies=1";
```