# Amazon remote log-in (PHP cURL) | Cookies

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to make a remote log-in for Amazon. So basically, an user will log-in through our local form. And if everything he filled in is correct, he will be logged in at Amazon.
`

```
            if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) 
                { 


                    $account = $_POST["account"];
                    $pass = $_POST["pass"];



                    $ch = curl_init("https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_ya_signin");  


                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 


                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ap_email=" .$account."&ap_password=".$pass."");  


                    curl_exec($ch);  


                    if (curl_errno($ch))  
                        { 
                               print curl_error($ch); 

                        } 
                    else 
                        { 
                            curl_close($ch);  

                        } 

                } 
            else 
                { 
            ?> 
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  ?>" name="login"> 
        <table width="100%"> 
            <tr align="center"> 
                <td width="50%" align="right"><font color="navy">E-Mail</font></td> 
                <td width="50%" align="left"><input type="text" name="account" size="10"></td> 
            </tr> 

            <tr align="center"> 
                <td width="50%" align="right" width="100"><font color="navy">Password</font></td> 
                <td width="50%" align="left"><input type="password" size="10" name="pass"></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr align="center"> 
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Inloggen"></td> 
            </tr> 

        </table> 
        </form> 
        <?php } ?>`
```

This is the code I've used. And I'm getting the following error:

**Please Enable Cookies to Continue**

**To continue shopping at Amazon.com, please enable cookies in your Web browser. Learn more about cookies and how to enable them.**

**Once you have enabled cookies in your browser, please click on the button below to return to the previous page.**

How can I fix this error? I've tried everything.

I'm using XAMPP at the moment.

Comment: Is setting `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` enough? You should try setting  `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` as well.

Comment: Take a look at the new post. I've added them both, but I'm getting a white window now.

Answer (score 0):

Just for marking as answer:

you have to 2 things:

1 - Request login page from server using get method

2 - Send login data using new session and with hidden inputs

to see the script : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532730/889678

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @SamerAlbadry put your url and parameter in my answer example post and try

Comment: @SamerAlbadry look the amazon login form it is posting to this url https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin

Comment: @SamerAlbadry secondly your posting variable must be this  email=".$username."&password=".$password not ap_email(it is id not name)

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I've made a new post with the new code. Is this correct? If it is, I'm getting a white screen now.

Comment: Thank you. I used the script but it's giving me: Failed to find log in form!