# Doesn’t my curl post request contains cookies?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, http-headers, http-post

I need to login to http://auto.vsk.ru/login.aspx making a post request to it from my site.
I wrote a js ajax function that sends post request to php script on my server, that sends cross-domain request via cUrl.

`post.php`

```
<?php

function request($url,$post, $cook)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cook,
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cook,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)"',
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
CURLOPT_REFERER => $url,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post,
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$result = request($_POST['url'], $_POST['data'], $_POST['cook']);

if ($result === FALSE) 
 echo('error');
else
 echo($result);

?>
```

Js code:

```
function postcross(path,data,cook,run)
{
requestsp('post.php','url='+path+'&data='+data+'&cook='+cook, run);
}

function requestp(path, data, run)
{
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', path, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() 
{  
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
{
    run(http);
}
}

http.send(data);
}

postcross('http://auto.vsk.ru/login.aspx',encodeURIComponent('loginandpassord'),'vskcookies.txt',function(e){
document.getElementById('container').innerText=e.responseText;
});
```

The html page I getting from response says two things:

1. My browser is not Internet Explorer, I should switch to it.(actually it works from Google Chrome, at least can login).
2. My browser doesn’t support cookies.

About the cookies it is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522149) (veeeery long) question. File `vskcookies.txt` is created in my server and it is actually updates after post request call, and stores cookies.

About the IE, firstly I thought that the site checks browser from js, but it is wrong, because js doesn’t run at all - I only read html page as a plain text, and it already has that notification about IE.

So wondered what if I make cUrl request wrong? I wrote new php script that shows request headers, here is a source:

`head.php`

```
<?php

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) 
{
echo "$name: $value\n";
}

?>
```

The result of `postcross('http://mysite/head.php',encodeURIComponent('loginandpassord'),'vskcookies.txt',function(e){ document.getElementById('container').innerText=e.responseText; })`:

```
Host: my site
User-Agent: "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)"
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: mysite/head
X-1gb-Client-Ip: my ip
X-Forwarded-For: ip, ip, ip
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Port: 443
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-URI: /head
X-Forwarded-Request: POST /head HTTP/1.1
X-Forwarded-Host: my site
X-Forwarded-Server: my site
Content-Length: 823
Connection: close
```

For some reason there is no `Cookie:` parameters, but user agent is IE as I mentioned.

Also I tried to replace `head.php` source with

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

And got empty array:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or it is site bot-protection?

---

**Update 1**

It is showing cookies only if to pass them through `CURLOPT_COOKIE`.

So I think I will leave `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cook;` as it is, and for `CURLOPT_COOKIE` something like `file_get_contents($cook)`, although there is useless information. protection?

---

**Important Update 2**

Okay, probably I just stupid. Response html page indeed consists messages about IE and offed cookies, but they are in div that is `display:none` and are displayed on by js.

So, seems my tries fail because of another reasons.

Comment: I'm confused about the part where the browser is expected to provide the server's local file system path for cookie jar file. That's the goal?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález didn’t understand You. You mean php `request` function? As I mentioned in question, the file `vskcookies.txt` in my server stores cookies after request.

Comment: `postcross('http://auto.vsk.ru/login.aspx',encodeURIComponent('loginandpassord'),'vskcookies.txt',function(e){` — Why must JavaScript send PHP server settings to PHP server?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, well in future, I was planning to automatically create cookies files depending on domain name. Currently it is just for comfort. There is a problem?

Comment: You're asking the user: What file on server do you want me to wipe out? (I'm not saying that's the issue, I'm just trying to understand the code).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález currently it’s only for me. What do You mean by Your first sentence? The only security thing I need to add is to block domains with `file://`.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't aware of how `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR ` works: it's a path, on **server's disc**, where PHP creates a **file** (ref.: [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), [2](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html)). You don't normally read it from `$_POST`, just like you don't read the session directory or the temp directory. Anyway, if you don't plan to upload your code to a hosting provider I guess it's fine.